# Proving $(\int_0^t f(X_s) dW_s)_{t \in [0T]}$, $f$ a $k$-Lipschitz function, is a continuous martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider $X =(X_t)_{t \in [0T]}$ progressively measurable with $X_t \in \mathbb L^p, \forall t \in [0,T]$ for $p\geq 1$ and $f$ a $k$-Lipschitz function.

I would like to show that $(\int_0^t f(X_s) dW_s)_{t \in [0T]}$  is a continuous martingale , where $W$ is the brownian motion.

Indeed, since $f$ is a $k$-Lipschitz function and by Jensen's inequality

\begin{align} \int_0^T \left| f(X_s)\right|^2 ~ ds &\leq \int_0^T\left( \left| f(X_0)\right| + k \left| X_0\right|+ k \left|X_s\right|\right)^2 ~ds \\
& \leq 3 \int_0^T \left| f(X_0)\right|^2 + k \left| X_0\right|^2+ k \left|X_s\right|^2 ~ds \\ 
& = 6k^2  \left| X_0\right|^2T+ 3k^2 \int_0^T \left|X_s\right|^2 ~ds \\
   \end{align}
\begin{align} \mathbb E\left[\int_0^T \left| f(X_s)\right|^2 ~ ds\right]&\leq  C_T\left( 1+ \mathbb E\left[\int_0^T \left|X_s\right|^2 ~ds\right]\right)  \\& \leq  C_T\left( 1+ T\ \mathbb E\left[\sup_{t\in [0,T]} \left|X_s\right|^2 \right]\right)< \infty \end{align}

with $C_T= \max \{6k^2  \mathbb E\left[ \left| X_0\right|^2\right]T ,3k \}$.

Could someone check if I made any mistake please ?

Comment: How do you know that the expectation $$\mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{t \in [0,T]} X_s^2 \right)$$ is finite if you only assume $X_t \in L^p$ for fixed $t$ and some $p \geq 1$?

Comment: @ Paul : Hi saz is right, now interchanging sup and expectation operator then the statement is true (if $X \in L^p$ for all p>1), but I don't know if it is enough or your purpose, by the way unless mistaken, if $X$ is itself a local martingale then applying Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality, your last inequality is true but with another constant (take a look at George Lowther's blog on the subject. Regards.